# Self-Hosted Document Editor (like Google Docs) - to print

Tags: pdf, editor, wysiwyg, document, google-docs

I am looking to facilitate the users of my website with a google-doc like text editor, where the user can write and format text in the context of an A4-page rather than a `HTML textbox`, which can be saved on server later on.

The idea is that, later I can proceed to print the file on server-side, without asking the user to go through the File->Print from his browser and then re-upload the locally saved PDF, instead I would generate a printable format of the input.

A simple `WYSIWIG` editor won't do I believe, as it will not be able to edit address fields inside it, but feel free to prove me wrong!

Thanks!

Comment: Slightly different but in the same context is http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus which is an XSL designer for merging data. It uses Summernote editor and customizations.